# Opposite of lastUnique()

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, epl

New to Esper and EPL in general, i have two use cases which are basically the opposites of oneanother. First I need to catch all unique events in a timewindow, using `firstunique(*parameters*).win:time(*time*)`.

Now what I need to do is the exact opposite, basically catch all events that arrive in that window and that are NOT thrown by that statement, basically all the duplicates.

How can I achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a solution, it involves using unique id's for incoming events on top of comparing their parameters.

The query looks something like this :

```
select * from Event a where exists (select * from Event.std:firstUnique(*parameters*).win:time(*time*) b where a.eventId <> b.eventId)
```

This solves the problem I had where the *exists* method would return every event (duplicates and unique events) because the window in the subquery would be filled first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery and "not exists". For example:

```
select * from Event e1 where not exists (select * from Event#firstunique(*parameters*)#time(*time*) e2 where e1.parameters = e2.parameters)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. First of all, I want the duplicates, so it should use *exists* and not *not exists*. But even then, the problem is it catches ALL the events because at the time it does the first query, the event has already been added in the subquery window and thus it acts like it's a duplicate when in fact it's not.